# Create a ListView containing both simple_list_item_1 and simple_list_item_multiple_choice on Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to follow this guide on creating a ListView with two different layouts to create an activity for a settings menu but some parts are ambiguous to me and my attempts aren't working.
http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

activity_settings.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.austin.kanadrill.SettingsActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/settingsListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

SettingsActivity.java

```java
package com.example.austin.kanadrill;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        ListView settingsListView = findViewById(R.id.settingsListView);
        SettingsAdapter settingsAdapter = new SettingsAdapter();
        settingsAdapter.addItem("Hiragana");
        settingsAdapter.addItem("Katakana");
        settingsAdapter.addItem("Fonts");
        settingsAdapter.addCheckBoxItem("Speed Mode");
        settingsListView.setAdapter(settingsAdapter);

    }

}
```

SettingsAdapter.java

```java
package com.example.austin.kanadrill;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class SettingsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    final int TYPE_CHECKBOX_ITEM = 1;
    final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = 2;
    Context ctx;

    ArrayList mData = new ArrayList();
    LayoutInflater mInflator;
    TreeSet mCheckBoxSet = new TreeSet();

    public SettingsAdapter() {
        mInflator = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addCheckBoxItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        mCheckBoxSet.add(mData.size()-1);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mCheckBoxSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_CHECKBOX_ITEM : TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return (String) mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        if(convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch(type) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    convertView = mInflator.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.settingsListView);
                    break;
                case TYPE_CHECKBOX_ITEM:
                    convertView = mInflator.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.settingsListView);
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView.setText((String)mData.get(position));
        return convertView;

    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
    }

}
```

I faced issues especially in the constructor for SettingsAdapter because I think I needed to create a context to call getSystemService() and I doubt I did that properly. I also did not understand exactly what to do in getView() so that is likely wrong too. My goal is to just have a ListView where the first three Strings are simple_list_item_1 and a fourth string is simple_list_item_multiple_choice. How can I fix this code to accomplish that, or just start from scratch?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues in your code

Pass the Activity context to Settings Apdapter, It must be throwing exception.

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
SettingsAdapter settingsAdapter = new SettingsAdapter(this);
```

**SettingsAdpater.java**

```
public SettingsAdapter(Context context) {
 ctx = context
 mInflator = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

and for textview id, use `android.R.id.text1` (that's the id defined in `R.layout.simple_list_item_1` and `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice`)

```
switch(type) {
    case TYPE_ITEM:
        convertView = mInflator.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        break;
    case TYPE_CHECKBOX_ITEM:
        convertView = mInflator.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, null);
        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        break;
}
```

Let me know if you didn't understand any part, happy to help.